# how to rest firestore sorted rules using Google Cloud SDK Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I got into a scenario where I reached the 2501 limit of my security rules allowed. Thus, when deploying, I have to be prompted to remove the last 10. Is there a decent way to reset back to 2491 rather than having to face the prompt after each 10 deploys?

is there a way to clear those stored rules using some command in Google Cloud SDK Shell or clear them manually from some bucket.

> i  storage: uploading rules storage-app.rules...
> i  storage: uploading rules storage-top-100k-customers.rules...
> i  storage: quota exceeded error while uploading rules
> ? You have 2501 rules, do you want to delete the oldest 10 to free up space? (y/N)

Answer (score 1):

All of the supported ways to manage and deploy with security rules are listed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy). Other than the CLI and the console, your only options are:

- The [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the_admin_sdk)
- The [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy#use_the_rest_api)

If you iterate a lot during development, you can save yourself a lot of hassle by using the [emulator suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) locally (which does support local [security rule evaluation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/use_extensions)) so that you don't have to deploy so much.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an issue with the current documentation regarding an argument passed to the listRulesetMetadata that didn't work out in my case, I conducted some tests and found out that I can get the data I need (all the rulesets ) just by calling the listRulesetMetadata() function. As a result, I created a cloud function that will delete all the older rule sets older than 30 days. This solution addresses a significant issue that any long-term project could face.

**However, be careful if you run this function later, as it could delete your current rules if they went unchanged for over a month..  So, I recommend running it only once, and then deleting it. If you need it again later, you can trigger it again.**

```js
// Note: Just for testing purposes I called it every 5 minutes you
// but the best thing it to call it only if you react the limit again... 
// since it could delete your current rules.. putting you in a position
// that is really hard to recover from if you depend only on rules being saved on the cloud ..  
exports.cleanupRulesets = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
  // Note: current firebase doc is wrong, and this fact has been metioned in previous questions.
  // * since the it asks to add page token arg to the listRulesetMetadata().
  // * however you can get the list of all rulesets without page token arg.

  // Get the list of all rulesets.
  const results = (await admin.securityRules().listRulesetMetadata()).rulesets;
  // Declare time condition.
  const thirtyDaysInMillis = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  const thirtyDays = new Date(Date.now() - thirtyDaysInMillis);

  const promises: any = [];
  // Loop over the results.
  results.forEach((el) => {
    if (new Date(el.createTime) < thirtyDays) {
      // Pick the rulesets that are older than 30 days.
      promises.push(admin.securityRules().deleteRuleset(el.name));
    }
  });
  // Exucute the promises.
  await Promise.all(promises);
  // Log the deleted rulesets.
  console.log(`Deleted ${promises.length} rulesets.`);

  return null;
});
```